# Importing a text file with a column with timestamps in the format HH:MM:SS

Tags: matlab, import

I want to import a txt file that has a column with timestamps in the format `HH:MM:SS`. I've tried a few different things but without luck. Hope someone can help, I have attached the table I'm trying to import and the matlab code I have tried using.

```
% Import the data from the text file
data = readtable('data.txt');

% Converting the time values to datetime format
time_values = datetime(data(:, 1), 'InputFormat', 'HH:mm:ss');

% Separating the remaining values into a separate variable or column
other_values = data(:, 2:end);
```

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 00.00.01 | 13,05254116 |
| 00.00.02 | 13,05254116 |
| 00.00.03 | 13,05254116 |
| 00.00.04 | 12,8976404 |
| 00.00.05 | 12,8976404 |
| 00.00.06 | 12,74349886 |
| 00.00.07 | 12,74349886 |
| 00.00.08 | 12,59011097 |
| 00.00.09 | 12,43747122 |

Getting help with my problem

Comment: You specify the `InputFormat` as `'HH:mm:ss'`, but the separator in your example data time column seem to be a simple `.`. Either try an `Inputformat` like `'HH.mm.ss'`, or you may have to substitute `.` for `:` in your time column before you convert it to a `datetime`.

Comment: I have tried doing that but get another problem, now when i try to import the file for instance in row 1 the number 13 is added in column 1 instead of column 2. So it looks like this: '00.00.01   13', as if it separates the numbers by the comma

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the import options, `readtable()` will scan the file and try to work out a lot of things by itself. Sometimes it gets things wrong unless you explicitely explain how to interpret the text. If you try a straight import of your file you get something like:

```
>> filename = 'timetableexample.txt' ;
data = readtable(filename)
data =
  9×2 table
         Var1            Var2  
    _______________    ________
    {'00.00.01 13'}     5254116
    {'00.00.02 13'}     5254116
      ...
```

Which is obviously wrong. There are several issues in the formating of your text file which are preventing `readtable` to do a smooth import of such a text file:

The first problem with your file is that the comma `,` will be detected on each line and `readtable` will interpret this as a column `delimiter`. This is why a direct import as you attempted end up splitting the table at the wrong place.

To alleviate that problem, we can specify the delimiter manually. I will assume that in your file the delimiter is a `space` character. Adjust the code accordingly if the real delimiter is a tabulation (use `'\t'` instead of `' '`).

First we get a `delimitedTextImportOptions` object by running the line:

```
opts = detectImportOptions(filename) ;
```

And you can verify that the automatic detection of the delimiter was indeed wrong:

```
>> opts.Delimiter
ans =
  1×1 cell array
    {','}
```

So we replace it with the right delimiter:

```
opts.Delimiter = {' '} ;
```

Now if you try to read the file with this new option, the column separation is correct but the import is still problematic:

```
>> data = readtable(filename,opts)
data =
  9×2 table
        Var1        Var2
    ____________    ____
    {'00.00.01'}    NaN 
    {'00.00.02'}    NaN
```

This is because the default decimal separator for Matlab is the dot `.`, and not the comma `,` as used in many european countries. To correct for that, we'll tell Matlab to import the column as text initialy (then we'll modify the text so Matlab can convert it to numbers).

For this, we'll need to modify another of the import option `VariableTypes`:

```
>> opts.VariableTypes
ans =
  1×2 cell array
    {'char'}    {'double'}
```

we replace this with:

```
opts.VariableTypes = {'char','char'} ;
```

And now finally:

```
data = readtable(filename,opts)
data =
  9×2 table
        Var1             Var2      
    ____________    _______________
    {'00.00.01'}    {'13,05254116'}
    {'00.00.02'}    {'13,05254116'}
```

Our columns are all imported properly, but only as text so far. Next we'll replace the unconventional characters in each column and replace them with what Matlab expects for the types present (`datetime` and `double`). We'll use the function `strrep()` for this. Then it becomes trivial to convert this text to the proper time/values.

---

I think what was bugging you was the mismatch between the automatic import options and your specific file formating. Now this is explained, I won't detail the code line by line but just give you the full code to import such a file:

```
filename = 'timetableexample.txt' ;
opts = detectImportOptions(filename);
% modify the import options we need
opts.Delimiter = {' '} ;
opts.VariableTypes = {'char','char'} ;

data = readtable(filename,opts) ;   % read the table

strTime = table2cell(data(:,1)) ;   % extract column 1 in a cell array
strTime = strrep(strTime,'.',':') ; % replace '.' with ':'

% Now you can convert to datetime object
time_values = datetime(strTime, 'InputFormat', 'HH:mm:ss') ;

strData = table2cell(data(:,2)) ;   % extract column 2 in a cell array
strData = strrep(strData,',','.') ; % replace ',' with '.'

% Convert cell array of char into a double array
other_values = str2double(strData) ;
```